# Fit 2 Graphs Side By Side in Shiny Navbar Page Without Using box()

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have an app where I would like to plot a graph and a datatable on the same row. I am using navbarPage. For some reason the column() function is not working and when I set the width to 50% they do not automatically move beside each other.

When I use box() I get the desired output.However I do not want a box and would rather have no space in between plots.

```
library(shinythemes)
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui = navbarPage("ETF Investor", theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
              tabPanel("ETF's",
                       plotOutput("hey", width = "50%"),
                           dataTableOutput("hi", width = "50%")





                       ),
              tabPanel("Screener"),
              tabPanel("Market Conditions"),
              tabPanel("Portfolio Builder"),
              tabPanel("Jordan's Portfolio"),
              tabPanel("Documentation")

    )



server <- function(input, output) {

    output$hey = renderPlot({
        hist(rnorm(100))
    })

    output$hi = renderDataTable({
        data.frame(a = rnorm(100), b = rnorm(100))
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here is my current output
[image]

And here is the semi desired output with box width set to 6 for each.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired behavior by placing both columns in a `fluidRow` and removing the `width=50%` from the individual output objects. A working example is given below, hope this helps!

---

[image]

---

```
library(shinythemes)
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui = navbarPage("ETF Investor", theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
                tabPanel("ETF's",
                         fluidRow(
                                  column(width=6,
                                         plotOutput("hey")
                                  ),
                                  column(width=6,
                                         dataTableOutput("hi")
                                  )
                         )

                ),
                tabPanel("Screener"),
                tabPanel("Market Conditions"),
                tabPanel("Portfolio Builder"),
                tabPanel("Jordan's Portfolio"),
                tabPanel("Documentation")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$hey = renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(100))
  })

  output$hi = renderDataTable({
    data.frame(a = rnorm(100), b = rnorm(100))
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```